# Autofilter Using Variable Array

Tags: arrays, vba, autofilter

I need to use a string of data for an autofilter field.  In the actual macro the creation of the string is more complicated and variable, but the below example recreates my problem more simply.

When I try to use a string variable into the autofilter, the autofilter hides everything.  When I use the same string but put it into the Array directly it works.  Can anyone help me with how to filter using an Array?

```
Term = """" & APR & """" & "," & """" & MAY & """"

Debug.Print Term     'just to verify the strings are the same

Arr1 = Array("APR", "MAY")   'works in the filter
Arr1 = Array(Term)           'fails in the filter

Worksheets("Filter").Range("$A:$H").AutoFilter Field:=2, _
    Criteria1:=Arr1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Dim APR As String
    Dim MAY As String
    Dim arr1(0 To 1) As String
    APR = "APR"
    MAY = "MAY"
    arr1(0) = APR
    arr1(1) = MAY
    Worksheets("Filter").Range("$A:$H").AutoFilter Field:=2, _
        Criteria1:=arr1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```